# react firebase project not updating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm

I've been working on a react project and tried to host it with firebase.

Everything was working fine. Everytime I make changes I test on localhost, run `npm run build` and then deploy with `firebase deploy`.

I was seeing the changes on the firebase website until it suddenly stoped updating. Although I didn't do anything strange before it happens (I was working on frontend and it stopped for no obvious reason).

In firebase console I can see that the deployments were successfully made.

I don't know if it's firebase that stopped updating or the `npm run build` that is not making changes.